# PtMumbai accuser error

Tags: baker, accuser

I just updated to V16.0 . I was able to bootstrap the baker for Mumbai . The accuser has an error. Lima baker is still endorsing and everything is running fine.

Comment: My question is why would the baker bootstrap for Mumbai , but the accuser will not. Why would the Lima baker still be running fine. Baking Benjamin’s took a look at it and suggested I post here as it may be an important clue for core devs.

Comment: Hi @jonathan-mangin ! Can you expand the question with the following details: the output error;  how you installed Octez v16.0 (binaries/opam/docker/built from scratch) and with your deployment system (e.g. systemd).

Comment: Error:
   Did not find service: GET http://local host:8732/monitor/apllied_blocks?next_protocol=PtMumbai2TmsJHNGRkD8v8YDbtao7BLUC3wjASn1inAKLFCjaH1&chain=main

I used the updates git fetch, git checkout v16.0, make build-deps, eval$(opam env), make 

./octez-accuser-PtMumbai run

Comment: Home brew on a Mac mini

Comment: This is the error that shows when I run the octez accuser command

Answer (score 1):

```
Error: Did not find service: GET localhost:8732/monitor/apllied_blocks?next_protocol=PtMumbai2TmsJHNGRkD8v8YDbtao7BLUC3wjASn1inAKLFCjaH1&chain=main
```

means that your accuser is connected to an octez-node that does not have the `/monitor/applied_blocks` RPC endpoint. This endpoint has been introduced in octez 16.

So, highly probably, you are trying to connect a >= 16.0 daemon to a <= 15.1 node.

Comment: I am connecting a 16.0 Daemon to an operating 15.1 node. My baker is bootstrapped. My accuser would not bootstrap. You are correct. How do I fix this ? Rewriting the command to launch the baker ?

Comment: PtMumbai cannot run on octez-node 15.1. Yes, your PtMumbai baker tell you for now "waiting for the protocol PtMumbai to start" which might give you the impression that it """works"" but PtMumbai will actually never ever "start" on a 15.1 node! Your 15.1 node will just crash at the activation of PtMumbai and your baker never does anything...

Comment: Thank you!  I have  ./octez-node run —rpc-addr 127.0.0.1:8732 &